# AC tripping power breaker

Tags: electrical, hvac, air-conditioning, central-air

My central AC is dripping power breaker

### What I have checked

1. Filters are clean
2. I cleaned outside unit with water
3. I put in a new capacitor

It cools fine it just trips middle of night like 4am

Comment: Is it trying to start when the breaker trips?  Also, what are the outdoor ambients you're dealing with, and the indoor setpoint for that matter?

Comment: Check freon and tighten all electrical connections including the wire attaching to the breaker itself.  A breaker that has tripped many times may need to be replaced, they weaken as they age and trip.  Also it's possible the start capacitor on the motor needs replacement.

Comment: Does it always trip at night?  What is the make and model of the condensing unit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was compressor coil needed cleaning

I used [Web Condenser Coil Cleaner](http://www.homedepot.com/p/14-oz-Condenser-Coil-Cleaner-WCOIL/100351663)

1. Turned off AC
2. Sprayed two cans of Web Condenser Coil Cleaner on all the sides
3. Let it sit there for 15 minutes
4. Washed with Water hose
5. let it dry for 30+ minutes
6. Turned off the unit

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have tried the basic items.

You could try replacing the breaker.

If you continue to have a problem then you will have to call an air conditioning service technician to check the unit out completely.

Good luck!